# How do I map multiple replace commands in visual mode

Tags: visual-mode, replace, key-bindings

I'm trying to edit my init.vim to allow quick, custom retabbing with one key. My current attempt is as follows (the replace text in the last command is a tab character inputted in insert mode):

```
nnoremap <C-i> :%s/\s\+$//ge<CR>:%s/ \{2,}/ /ge<CR>
vmap <C-i> :'<,'>s/\s\+$//ge<CR>:'<,'>s/ \{2,}/ /ge<CR>
```

The normal mode map works perfectly, but I can't figure out why the visual map doesn't. The only thing it does is report:

```
E488: Trailing characters
```

Why doesn't the visual map work the same way as the normal mode map, and is what I'm attempting impossible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `'<,'>` in your first command get inserted automatically when entering `:` from visual mode. Remove them.

Comment: Also you don’t need `vmap`; just `vnoremap`

Comment: `xnoremap` to map only visual mode without mapping select mode. See `:h map-modes`

Comment: @PeterRincker agreed

Comment: Thanks! My retabbing works now!